# What was happening to Joshu Kasei at Sybil's core?

Tags: psycho-pass

Spoilers for the latest episodes of Psycho-Pass.

---

During the riots, Kagari and Choe enter Sybil's core. There, Joshu Kasei forces a dominator into lethal mode to kill Choe. Then, she kind of melts down before killing Kagari as well.

> [image]

Why was she melting down (her chin kind of falls down)? At first I'd have guessed it was because she was forcing the dominator, but later we see she can change their behavior with ease.

Comment: If I recall correctly, she is attacked with acid just before that.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Hm, although I can't remember any such attack, she was looking just fine before shooting Choe. It was after killing him that she begun to look melted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choe attacks her with some acid just before that. It obviously didn't work quite as expected.

[image]

Comment: This does not seem like a very good answer. You should probably expand it a bit more. For example maybe references to the episode or something.

Comment: @アズーサ The reference to the episode is that it happens in this episode. Like literally seconds before the event being asked about. So what standard of proof is considered necessary here?

Comment: Well looking at your answer its a bit too short, doesn't provide links and I think more should perhaps be added. It might be better as a comment though.

Comment: @アズーサ It is already comment, but it is also an answer, because there is nothing deeper going on here. No philosophical dance about literature here. Dude just fired acid at her. I suppose a trivial Google search will yield an image of this act. Would that be satisfactory? Anyone who watched should have seen Choe clearly fire something at her. At worst there is a question of what, until we see her face dripping off.

Comment: in response to your edit summary comment, i can't find any highly up voted accepted answer which was is just one line and didn't have an image associated with it. remember there are ~4,700 answers across hundreds of tags so not one persona can go though all of them and edit them accurately without having to have seen every anime/manga/light novel/visual novel, especially with some answers being a couple of years old and those who can fix/identify them just don't know they exists